# How to transform this raw SQL query into Laravel Eloquent :)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to transform this raw SQL query into Laravel Eloquent :)

```
SELECT
    a_tables.`id` AS `a_id`,
    b_tables.`id` AS `b_id`,
    c_tables.`id` AS `c_id`
FROM
    laravel.a_tables AS P
        LEFT JOIN laravel.b_tables AS L ON L.`a_tables_id` = `a_id` AND L.user_id=2
        LEFT JOIN laravel.c_tables AS I ON I.`a_tables_id`  = `a_id` AND I.`b_tables_id` = `b_id` AND I.user_id=2
    WHERE
        P.user_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DB::table("laravel.a_tables as p")
         ->leftJoin("laravel.b_tables as l", function($join){
              $join->on("l.a_tables_id", "=", "p.id")
              ->where("l.user_id", "=", 2);
          })
         ->leftJoin("laravel.c_tables as i", function($join){
              $join->on("i.a_tables_id", "=", "p.id")
              ->where("i.b_tables_id", "=", "l.id")
              ->where("i.user_id", "=", 2);
          })
         ->select("p.id as a_id", "l.id as b_id", "i.id as c_id")
         ->where("p.user_id", "=", 2)
         ->get();
```

Comment: This is not Eloquent.  [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent) != [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries).

Comment: god bless you!!